# Using operators in "find"

Tags: macos, bash, find

I apologise if this had already been covered before. I am learning `find` on my OSX Mavericks. I am not quite sure I fully understand the operators.

My folder has 4 files:

```
123.123
123.abc
abc.123
abc.abc
```

When I try to "OR" `-o` operator:

```
find . \( -name "*.123" -o -name "123.*" \) -print
```

Output is as expected:

```
./123.123
./123.abc
./abc.123
```

But when I take away the bracket / parentheses, i.e.:

```
find . -name "*.123" -o -name "123.*" -print
```

... only `./123.abc` is printed.

Why....??? I really don't understand how the command is being interpreted by the computer here.

My observation is that `./123.abc` fits the second argument (`123.*`), but not the first (`*.123`). So it seems somehow, the use of `-o` before the second argument without brackets lead to the first argument behaving as if it had a "NOT" (`!`) operator.

Comment: By the way you get the expected output if you omit the `-print` like `find . -name "*.123" -o -name "123.*"` (at least on GNU)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a question of [operator precedence](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Order_of_operations#Programming_languages) between the *"and"* and *"or"* operators.

```
find . -name "*.123" -o -name "123.*" -print
```

is in fact

```
find . -name "*.123" -o -name "123.*" -a -print
```

As *and* has higher priority, this is interpreted as:

```
find . -name "*.123" -o \( -name "123.*" -a -print \)
```

If you want your expected behaviour *without* parenthesis, write that:

```
sh$ find . -name "*.123" -o -name "123.*"
./abc.123
./123.abc
./123.123
```

Here the "print" action is implied, and not subject to grouping.

If you want the full-verbose equivalent, you could write:

```
sh$ find . -name "*.123" -a -print -o -name "123.*" -a -print
./abc.123
./123.abc
./123.123
```

Which is interpreted as:

```
find . \( -name "*.123" -a -print \) -o \( -name "123.*" -a -print \)
```

Comment: Thank you for the detailed explanation!! That makes a lot of sense! Can I just quickly ask, is that operator precedence ("AND" has higher precedence than "OR") universal or at least in Bash or C programming)?

Comment: @LD99 My mistake: I thought I made the link to the ["operator precedence" Wikipedia article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Order_of_operations#Programming_languages). That being said, there is no such thing as "universal" considering the vast variety of available languages. For [C and most (all?) its derived, `&&` has higher priority than `||`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Operators_in_C_and_C%2B%2B#Operator_precedence). On the other hand, [in Bash `&&` and `||` have the same priority](http://unix.stackexchange.com/a/88851/40697)

Answer (score 3):

Taking bracket out makes `-print` action execute for this condition only:

```
-name "123.*"
```

Which prints: `./123.abc`

Comment: Thank you for the response, but if only `-name "123.*"` is executed, then wouldn't the output print both `123.abc` AND `123.123`?

Comment: It doesn't print `123.123` because earlier condition `-name "*.123"` also matched `123.123` and since that condition had no action it didn't print. If you create another file `123.aaa` it will be printed.

Comment: Ok... I get it!! So because the `123.123` was picked up by the first argument and there was no action associated with it, nothing was done. Then the same file was not matched with the second argument because it had already been matched. So really I was performing `find . -name "*.123" -o \( -name "123.*" -print \)`!! Great, it's all making sense now!! Thank you so much for your help.